# How to verify a method was called inside another method with Mockito

Tags: java, methods, mocking, mockito, verify

I'm fairly new to Mockito, and I've been looking for a way to verify that if I call the filter() method with the right string, that the foo method will get called once.

```
public class A
{
    private final Config _config;    

    public A(Config config) { _config = config; }

    public void filter(String str)
    {
        if(str.startsWith("a"))
        {
            if(str.contains("z"))
            {
                foo(config.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    private void foo(String bar)
    {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Here is my current code:

```
@Test
public void testOne()
{
    Config config = new Config(configFile);
    A a = Mockito.spy(new A(config));
    a.filter("abcz");
    verify(a, times(1)).foo(someString);
}
```

Comment: Have you researched this? I'm pretty sure this is pretty straightforward to do with Mockito.

Comment: Is the `foo` method another method from the `A` `class` (not shown here)?

Comment: @BeUndead The foo method is in the same class, sorry for not including it, should I update the code?

Comment: If the code is accurate, you can't verify `private` methods with `Mockito`.  [`PowerMockito#verifyPrivate`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html#verifyPrivate-java.lang.Class-) does do this though.

Comment: @BeUndead Yes, you are right, changed it to package private.

Comment: If it's just package-private, then make your test in the same package, create a `spy` around your test-instance, and use `verify(instance).foo("expectedString")`.

Comment: @asakusa don't make methods public just for tests, and don't use force to test private methods. You could make test here. If you couldn't make test, then refactor code. Main point here:"Don't change business logic classes just for tests reason"

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more generic while such a test. If you don't need to specify what exactly argument should by passed then just use `any()`:

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;

verify(a).foo(any(String.class));
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.